# How to fix 'Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: zero non-NA points' error in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to replicate [this visualization (for practice)](https://fivethirtyeight.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/silver-feature-most-common-women-names3.png?w=575).

The issue I am facing is this error that says

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: zero non-NA points.

I can't seem to figure out what's going on.
I've tried removing the `est_alive_today` variable, and it generated a plot, but the data looks quite off (so it appears that the variable is important in the accurate generation of the plot).

```
library(babynames)
library(Hmisc)
library(ggplot2)

BabynamesDist <- make_babynames_dist()
data("babynames")
com_fem <- na.omit(com_fem)
com_fem <- BabynamesDist %>%
  filter(sex == "F") %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(N = n(), 
            est_num_alive = sum(est_alive_today),
            q1_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, est_alive_today, probs = 0.25),
            median_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, est_alive_today, probs = 0.5),
            q3_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, est_alive_today, probs = 0.75)) %>%
  arrange(desc(est_num_alive)) %>%
  head(25)

w_plot <- ggplot(data = com_fem, 
                 aes(x = reorder(name, -median_age), y = median_age)) + 
  xlab(NULL) + ylab("Age (in years)") +
  ggtitle("Median ages for females with the 25 most common names")
w_plot <- w_plot + 
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = q1_age, ymax = q3_age),
                 color = "#f3d478", size = 10, alpha = 0.8)
w_plot <- w_plot +
  geom_point(fill = "#ed3324", colour = "white", size = 4, shape = 21)
w_plot +
  geom_point(aes(y = 55, x = 24), 
             fill = "#ed3324", colour = "white", size = 4, shape = 21) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 58, x = 24, label = "median")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 26, x = 16, label = "25th")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 51, x = 16, label = "75th percentile")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = 24, x = 16), shape = 17) +
  geom_point(aes(y = 56, x = 16), shape = 17) +
  coord_flip()
```

I should be getting a plot (not quite a clone of the one I put a picture link of above), but somewhat close enough.

My actual result is the error:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: zero non-NA points.

What can I do?

Comment: First thing you can do is tell us which line is causing the error, and only post code up to that point. I would guess its the `summarize` function but you should always create minimal exampes.

Comment: @Spacedman I'm not even sure what line is causing the error - that's also part of the issue, I suppose.

Comment: Start with the first line. Run it. If it doesn't error, add the second line. Repeat. And by "line" I mean syntactically complete R expression, which might span multiple lines in the file. If you pipe things, add bits to the pipe expression until you find one that triggers the error.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for the com_fem assigment

```
com_fem <- BabynamesDist %>%
  filter(sex == "F") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(
    N = n(),
    est_num_alive = sum(est_alive_today)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(desc(est_num_alive)) %>% 
  head(25) %>% 
  select(name) %>% 
  left_join(., BabynamesDist, by = "name") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(
    N = n(),
    est_num_alive = sum(est_alive_today),
    q1_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, weight = est_alive_today, probs = 0.25),
    median_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, weight = est_alive_today, probs = 0.5),
    q3_age = wtd.quantile(age_today, weight = est_alive_today, probs = 0.75) 
  )
```

Props to this site: http://www.sci.csueastbay.edu/~esuess/classes/Statistics_651/Presentations/03_ggplot2_02/ggplot2_02_examples.Rmd